# Unique Events (New) in the API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Reading these:

http://www.internetrix.com.au/blog/google-analytics-unique-events-are-dead-long-live-unique-events/

https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/google-analytics-new-event-metrics-explained/

I'd like to know what is the status of "Unique Events (New)" in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that so far the Unique Events has changed in the Analytics GUI **but not in the API**. At least my results today, running the API from Google Sheets gets the same result for ga:uniqueEvents and ga:uniqueDimensionCombinations (see below)

**This is what Analytics API Change log said on 2016-09-26:**

Metric - ga:uniqueEvents - **The definition of ga:uniqueEvents will change soon** to more accurately reflect the number of unique events. Please use ga:uniqueDimensionCombinations instead if you want to retain the existing definition. For more information, see Unique Events help documents.

Metric - ga:uniqueDimensionCombinations - Unique Dimension Combinations counts the number of unique dimension-value combinations for each dimension in a report. This lets you build combined (concatenated) dimensions post-processing, which allows for more flexible reporting without having to update your tracking implementation or use additional custom-dimension slots. For more information, see Unique Events help documents.